# Why is template argument deduction failing for pointer-to-member-function?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

With g++ 5.4, this

```
struct B {
    void f() {}
}; 

struct D : public B {
    void g() {}
};

template <class T>
void foo(void (T::*)(), void (T::*)())
{}

int main()
{
    foo(&D::f, &D::g);
}
```

fails due to "deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘T’ (‘B’ and ‘D’)".  Why isn't T deduced as D, being an exact match?

Comment: Maybe because there's no `D::f`? Only `B::f` exists, so `&D::f`'s type is `B::*`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to [**VTT**'s excellent demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47201454/817643). The standard text in question, I believe, is at [[expr.unary.op]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary.op#3), emphasis mine:

> The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The
>   operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id. **If the operand is a
>   qualified-id naming a non-static or variant member m of some class C
>   with type T, the result has type “pointer to member of class C of type
>   T” and is a prvalue designating C​::​m**.

The qualified id you used is `D::f`, but it names a member function of `B` (I can bring up the lookup rules if you want). So the class type `C` in the above paragraph, is `B`. The type therefore resolves to `void ( B::* )(void)`.

Comment: I was unconvinced initially, but I see from [class.mem] - "The member-specification in a class definition declares the full set of members of the class; no member can be added elsewhere." - that f is unequivocally a member of B and not a member of D, despite the D:: nested-name-specifier.

Answer (score 13):

The type of `&D::f` would be `void ( B::* )(void)`

```
static_assert(::std::is_same<void ( B::* )(void), decltype(&D::f)>::value, "");
static_assert(::std::is_same<void ( D::* )(void), decltype(&D::f)>::value, ""); // error
static_assert(::std::is_same<void ( D::* )(void), decltype(&D::g)>::value, "");
```

The rationale behind this is that otherwise you won't be able to assign a value of `&D::f` to a variable of `void ( B::* )(void)` type without a cast even though `f` is a member of `B` or compare `&D::f == &B::f`.

As a workaround you can perform a static_cast:

```
foo(static_cast<void (D::*)(void)>(&D::f), &D::g);
```

Comment: For me, it is hard to accept the rationale. If I'd want to assign `&D::f` to a `B::*`, then I'd refer it as `&B::f`. This behavior of C++ is unexpected, I've met this phenomenon several times in the past. Why does the type of `&D::f` change whether there is an actual `f` in `D`? I understand the working behind this, but cannot accept it. As a user of `B` & `D`, I don't care, whether the person who created `B` or `D` added an `f` to `D` or not.

Comment: an easier workaround would be `foo<D>(&D::f, &D::g)`

Comment: @geza But this way `&D::f == &B::f` is correctly evaluated to `true` which makes perfect sense to me because `f` refers to the same function in base class.